# Swift Reload textfield from button action

Tags: iphone, swift, ios8

I have a button that creates many more buttons with a textfield:

```
func CreateButtonWithIndex(index:Int) {
  let newButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
  newButton.setTitle(“Button”, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
  newButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("go:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

  newButton.tag = index+1;
  var textFieldButton: UITextField = UITextField()
  textFieldButton.tag = index+1;
  textFieldButton.text = “textfield”
  self.view.addSubview(textFieldButton)
  self.view.addSubview(newButton)
}

func go(sender: AnyObject) {
   println(“ok press button“)
}
```

How can I detect the textfield corresponding to the button pressed?

Answer (score 0):

convert the sender into a UIButton

```
@IBAction func go(sender: AnyObject) {
   let yourButton = sender as UIButton

   println(yourButton.titleLabel.text)

}
```

Even better, if you're certain that only buttons are going to call the "`go`" action, you could instead do this:

```
@IBAction func go(sender: UIButton) {

    println(sender.titleLabel.text)

    if(sender.titleLabel.text == "OK")
        println("OK button was pressed")

}
```

And more information can be found in the "Comparing Strings" section of [Apple's Strings & Characters Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html) and the @IBOutlet thing I found [in this tutorial](http://makeapppie.com/tag/swift-programming-2/).

Comment: i have error uibutton does not have member named "title "

Comment: yeah... I fixed my source example. I've been mixing too much MacOS & iOS stuff recently. "`yourButton.titleLabel.text`" is the way to do it.

Comment: but UiLabel don't have member named "text" but through the tags?

Comment: A `UILabel` object (i.e. the title label) has [a property named ".`text`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/text)

Answer (score 0):

Subclass UIButton.  Add a UITextField variable to the subclassed UIButton.  Assign the new UITextField variable after you create the UIButton subclass.

UIButton subclass:

```
class TextFieldButton: UIButton {
    var textField: UITextField! // use this to reference the related text field
}
```

The code in your other class:

```
    func CreateButtonWithIndex(index:Int) {
        let newButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as TextFieldButton // use our new subclass
        newButton.setTitle(“Button”, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        newButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("go:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        newButton.tag = index+1;
        var textFieldButton: UITextField = UITextField()
        textFieldButton.tag = index+1;
        textFieldButton.text = "textfield"

        newButton.textField = textFieldButton  // set reference to the text field
        self.view.addSubview(textFieldButton)
        self.view.addSubview(newButton)
    }

    func go(sender: AnyObject) {
        println("ok press button")
        println(sender.textField) // now we can access the related text field
    }
```

Comment: no error on let newButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as TextFieldButton // use our new subclass

Comment: Are you saying there is an error?  If so, what is the error?